# create a dash prompt

Tags: prompt, dash

When I log in to my server which has `dash` as default shell, I get a prompt that looks like this:

```
\[\033[1;31m\]\u\[\033[0m\]@:\w #
```

How can I configure the server that it shows something like this?

```
user@hostname!dash!/path/$
```

And in case, I have to put this in `.profile`, how can I keep the fancy shell in other shells like `bash` and `zsh`?

(On my server `.profile` is a symlink to `.bashrc`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dash is designed to be a minimal shell for fast script execution. Being comfortable for interactive use is very much not a design goal. If you want a fancy prompt, use a shell designed for interactive use: zsh, fish, or at least bash. The escape sequences you show are for bash.

Dash does expand variables in the prompt, so you can set a prompt like this in `.profile` (and override it in `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, etc.).

```
: "${USER=$(id -un)}" "${HOSTNAME=$(uname -n)}"
if [ $0 = "-sh" ]; then
  export PS1='$USER@$HOSTNAME!$0!:$PWD/\$ '
fi
```

Comment: @rubo77 Dash doesn't have an interactive startup file. You can put `export PS1='$USER@$HOSTNAME:$PWD/\$ '` in your `.profile`. But really, you shouldn't use dash interactively. You'll very quickly run into something else you don't like, such as the lack of command line edition.

Comment: sure, but I would like to put "dash" iside the prompt, so everybody gets a hint, that he's on dash

Comment: @rubo77 You can check `$0`, or detect bash (with `BASH_VERSION`), ksh (with `KSH_VERSION`), etc. and consider dash the fallback case. Or you can set a prompt for dash in `.profile`, and the capable shells will overwrite that setting in their interactive startup file.

Comment: you of course could also test in your `.profile` whether `HOSTNAME` is set, and if not, set it explicitly to the name of your host (or the output of `hostname` if you use the same `.profile` for several machines).

Comment: @Gilles Ref. last edit, [`dash` does not set `HOSTNAME`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dash/+bug/64184) so you'll need explicitly set it in `.profile` as [celtschk suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158313/create-a-dash-prompt/158314#comment259378_158314).

Comment: @rubo77 Ref. rejected edit, some consider executing commands as part of `PS1` bad style since this causes the commands to be executed each time the 1st level prompt is shown. Setting `HOSTNAME=$(hostname)` in `.profile` avoids this.

Comment: In OSX dahs doesn't seem to automatically read `.profile` any suggestion?

Comment: @Purefan What's dahs? Did you mean dash? It reads `.profile` if it's invoked as a login shell. That's true on OSX like everywhere else. What does this have to do with this question anyway? If you have a different problem, ask a new question.